# How do you write a fun that's recursive in Erlang?

Tags: recursion, erlang

I'm trying to write a recursive fun in an Erlang shell, but I keep getting an unbound variable exception:

```
1> Foo = fun(X) -> Foo(X) end.
* 1: variable 'Foo' is unbound
```

This probably goes without saying, but I'm not trying to create an infinite loop! This is just a simple example of the error I'm getting.

Comment: "Funs with Names": http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0037.html, which was merged into Erlang in late 2012.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Since [OTP 17.0](http://www.erlang.org/download_release/24) there are named funs:

```erlang
1> Perms = fun F([]) -> [[]]; F(L) -> [[H|T] || H <- L, T <- F(L--[H])] end.    
#Fun<erl_eval.30.54118792>
2> Perms([a,b,c]).
[[a,b,c],[a,c,b],[b,a,c],[b,c,a],[c,a,b],[c,b,a]]
```

Before that you could do this with a little argument trick:

```
1> Foo = fun(F, X) -> F(F, X) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.113037538>
2> Foo(Foo, a).
<...infinite loop!>
```

The trick here is to send in the function as an argument to itself to allow recursion.

Alternative way to make it in one shoot:

```
1> Foo = fun(X) -> Fun = fun(F,Y) -> F(F,Y) end, Fun(Fun,X) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.13229925>
2> Foo(a).
```

For example:

```
1> Foo = fun(Max) ->
1>     Fun = fun(F, X) when X > Max -> [];
1>              (F, X) -> [X | F(F, X+1)]
1>           end,
1>     Fun(Fun, 0)
1> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.13229925>
2> Foo(10).
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: I have no experience with Erlang, but it would seem to me that the two arguments a and Foo should be reversed...

Comment: Does this answer portend the Y-combinator, as mentioned in another answer here?

Comment: Well, you could see it as a self-contained ("poor man's") Y-combinator perhaps...

Comment: @AdamLindberg: I like to call it half Y-combinator.

Answer (score 22):

After Erlang 17, you can also use the ["Funs with names"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199177/funs-names-in-erlang-17) variant:

```
Foo = fun F(X) -> F(X) end.
```

In this way it is easier to understand that `F` is the function itself within the definition. Also, `Foo` and `F` can be the same variable.

Comment: Super! It is worked! I like this functionality very much! This solution is simple and convenient.

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, you can use the Y combinator. [Y Combinator in Erlang](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/070611.html) explains.

Comment: Learning about the Y-combinator has been on my list of things to learn for a long time. Thanks for pointing out the opportune moment :). For people who know Scheme, I thought the following page was useful: http://dangermouse.brynmawr.edu/cs245/ycomb_jim.html

Comment: Tim, I think this answer could have been better had you briefly mentioned what the Y-combinator is about. I probably would have accepted this answer had you done that.

Comment: The link in the answer didn't work for me, but I found [part 1](http://bytecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/01/deriving-y-combinator-in-erlang-or.html) and [part 2](http://bytecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/01/deriving-y-combinator-in-erlang-part-2.html) of this walk-through on implementing the y combinator in erlang extremely helpful. I'm still wrapping my head around it, but it's a nice step-by-step just like the one for Scheme above.

Comment: The link is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

I had a need to quickly send some packets over UDP for testing and here is how I have done it using the samples above:

```
Sendtimes = fun F(0,Socket) -> ok;
        F(Times,Socket) -> gen_udp:send(Socket, {127,0,0,1}, 5555, ["Message #:" ++ [Times]]),
        F(Times-1,Socket) end.
```

Answer (score -2):

Obviously, Foo gets assigned only after the fun is defined, so it may not be accessed from within it.

I don't think that Erlang allows to call the anonymous function from itself. Just make it a named one.