# Erlang: how can I reference an anonymous function from within the body?

Tags: erlang

In [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)) is there a way reference the currently executing function)?

That would be useful to spawn an infinite loop:

```
spawn(fun() -> do_something, this_fun() end)
```

In JavaScript `arguments.callee` does just that, see the specification on [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee).

Edit to answer a 'why would you do that': mostly curiosity; it is also useful to define a timer when prorotyping:

```
Self = self(),
spawn(fun() -> Self ! wake_up, receive after 1000 -> nil end, this_fun() end),
%% ...
```

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: This has also been answered in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867418/how-do-you-write-a-fun-thats-recursive-in-erlang/867525#867525

Comment: "Funs with Names": http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0037.html, which was merged into Erlang in late 2012.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Erlang/OTP 17.0 and later, you can use a named fun for that:

```
1> Self = self(),
1> Fun = fun ThisFun() ->
             Self ! wake_up,
             receive after 1000 -> nil end,
             ThisFun()
         end.
#Fun<erl_eval.44.71889879>
2> spawn(Fun).
<0.35.0>
3> flush().
Shell got wake_up
Shell got wake_up
Shell got wake_up
ok
```

---

In earlier versions, there is no way to do exactly that.  You could pass the function itself as an argument:

```
Self = self(),
Fun = fun(ThisFun) ->
          Self ! wake_up,
          receive after 1000 -> nil end,
          ThisFun(ThisFun)
      end
spawn(fun() -> Fun(Fun) end),
%% ...
```

Answer (score 7):

If you feel like twisting things a little bit:

```
Y = fun(M,B) -> G = fun(F) -> M(fun() -> (F(F))() end, B) end, G(G) end.
spawn(Y(fun(F, ParentPid) -> fun() -> ParentPid ! wake_up, receive after 1000 -> ok end, F() end end, self())).
```

Flush the messages couple times to see the result:

```
flush().
```

Of course, Y is more useful if you put it in some sort of library.
Also you can find [this post on Y Combinators](https://web.archive.org/web/20130718234532/http://bc.tech.coop/blog/070611.html) quite interesting

Answer (score 3):

The Erlang language does not expose any way for anonymous functions to refer to them self, but there is a rumour that Core Erlang (an intermediate but official representation in the compiler phases) does have such a feature.

I don't know why I am forwarding this, but you know, if you happen to be generating Core Erlang in a DSL or similar it is something that is within reach.