# Funs names in Erlang 17

Tags: erlang

Erlang 17 was released. And according to [Erlang OTP 17.0 has been released](http://www.erlang.org/news/73):

> Funs can now be given names

No examples are given.

Any ideas how to assign names to funs in Erlang 17?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Joe Armstrong explains it in his [blog post](http://joearms.github.io/2014/02/01/big-changes-to-erlang.html) with an example.

```
1> F = fun F(0) -> 1; 
           F(N) -> N * F(N - 1) 
       end.
#Fun
```

Previously you have to pass in the function as one of the args for anonymous recursive calls. (Think of y-combinator).

```
1> F = fun(F, 0) -> 1;
          (F, N) -> N*F(F, N-1)
       end.
#Fun
```

Answer (score 3):

Named funs are a implementation of [EEP37](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0037.html) see the link for a detailed description and rationale.

Answer (score 0):

This version doesn't need to pass in the function as one of the args:

`1> Fac = fun(Num) -> 
          Foo = fun(F, 0) -> 1; 
                   (F, N) when N > 0, is_integer(N) -> N *  F(F, N -1) end,
          Foo(Foo, Num) end.`